# Language independent formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like to prepare an overview tab with some formulas, though not all colleagues use an en-us version of Excel - I currently use de-at languages pack. Therefore I started using .FormulaLocal but it doesn't quite work in my case

In this example I try to prepare a formula that sums up all "light" errors from various tabs. I have two versions

**Version 1** (does work with de-at Excel)

```
Sub count_light_errors(tabName)
Dim element As Variant
Dim formula As String
Dim temp As Variant

For Each element In tabName
    temp = temp & "zählenwenn(" & element & "!E:E;""light"");"
Next element

formula = "=summe(" & Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1) & ")"
Worksheets("Overview").Range("C8").FormulaLocal = formula

End Sub
```

**Version 2** (does not work with de-at Excel)

```
Sub count_light_errors(tabName)
Dim element As Variant
Dim formula As String
Dim temp As Variant

For Each element In tabName
    temp = temp & "countif(" & element & "!E:E,""light""),"
Next element

formula = "=sum(" & Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1) & ")"
Worksheets("Overview").Range("C8").FormulaLocal = formula

End Sub
```

The difference between those two is just using the German words for

- SUM() -> SUMME()
- COUNTIF() -> ZÄHLENWENN()

and
; instead of , as seperator

How do I prepare formulas correctly, so they are independent from the user language pack?

Thanks a million!
-Claus

Comment: on the second, change `FormulaLocal` to `Formula`

Comment: wow, that was quick and easy - I'm impressed - thanks!