# How to create interface language independent WorksheetsFunction within VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Running a VBA function which uses the excel SUM function seems to not work when Excel uses another interface language.

Here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425122/language-independent-formulas) some have encounterd language issues but this is related to putting formulas language independent in cells.

```
Function sum_value(sum_range) As Single
    sum_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sum_range)
End Function
```

sum_value(1,2,3) = 6

**Solution**
On the Microsoft site I could not find that it is possible to use WorksheetFunctions as methods of the application Object. Relevant documentation below:

- [Excel application object Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object))
- [WorksheetFunction Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to be able to use the English functions as well? Unless you completely omit words in your `UDF`, it won't *really* be language independent.

Place this function in a module.

```
Public Function SUM(Range As Range) as Long

SUM = Application.SUM(Range)

End Function
```

Calling the `SUM()` function should then be possible within the WS.

In VBA, EN-US functions can *always* be used.

- `.Formula` uses English formulas
- `.FormulaLocal` uses formulas based on the regional version
- The same counts for `.FormulaR1C1` and `.FormulaR1C1Local`

Comment: Yes, the functions will be written in English to ease collaboration on the code, However I cant force users to use a certain language. 
So the option you suggested is to be used within the worksheet, not within VBA?
To be able to use EN function within VBA it would look something like
```
sum_value = sum_range.formula = "sum()"
```

Comment: If you're not planning to place formulas in a sheet with VBA, I don't see the problem. You should be able to use `Application.Sum()` without trouble.

Comment: Great! I could not find documentation directly on the microsoft site that you can use WorksheetFunctions as Methods of the application object.