# Excel formula problem with sumifs with multiple search values in one if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using sumifs to identify in a data table cost entries using "cost positions". These have typically numbers such as 100, 200 etc. But the intermediate numbers 101, 102 also exist but must be neglected.

Currently I have the search number in a cell named "position" and search for my data using the table name Cost with entry Position: "Cost[Position]"

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];Position)
```

This works for a single value, but I want to search for a list of values, such as "100, 200, 400, 500". But I do not want to add an if entry for each value, since I never know if it is 1, 2 or 10 values.

Is this possible?

The dumb way of doing this would be to add all the values.

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];Position1)
 +SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];Position2)
```

Comment: Should be like this: `=SUM(SUMIFS(Cost[Wert/BWähr],Cost[Position],{100,200,500,etc}))` , I think you wrote the formula in `German Language` then it will be like `=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];{100.200.500.etc}))`

Comment: Create a vertical or horizontal range of those positions in some place and use it as `Criteria`. or, you can do `=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];UNIQUE(Cost[Position])))`

Comment: Refer this one. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77845767/make-a-summation-in-excel-by-several-criteria)

Comment: I realized you need something like this. `=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];SEQUENCE(ZEILEN(UNIQUE(Cost[Position]));;100;100)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, from your OP then you would need a formula like this:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E5</kbd>

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D5:D24,C5:C24,SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(C5:C24)),,100,100)))
```

---

In German Version of Excel it will be:

```
=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(D5:D24;C5:C24;SEQUENCE(ZEILEN(UNIQUE(C5:C24));;100;100)))
```

---

For your data in context it will be:

```
=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];SEQUENCE(ZEILEN(UNIQUE(Cost[Position]));;100;100)))
```

---

So how does this formula works:

- Using `UNIQUE()` function extracting the unique positions.
- Using `ROW()` function getting the number of unique rows.
- Using `SEQUENCE()` function getting the positions sequence starting from `100` and incrementing each by `100` as well ( The reason behind to use this because its clearly mentioned in your post --> *These have typically numbers such as 100, 200 etc.* <--. and hence creating the same sequence we can escape the intermediate numbers).
- Using the above as `criteria` in `SUMIFS()` function, while the rest follows as per the syntax of the said function.
- Lastly, wrapping within, `SUM()` function to get the total of the values returned in the array.

---

```
=LET(α, Cost[Position], SUM(SUMIFS(Cost[Wert/BWähr],α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(α)),,100,100))))
```

---

Comment: It does work if changed manually, however I add this formula in VBA in there an @ is added to the sequence. How can I suppress the addition of @. The code looks like this `ws.Cells(4, col).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(...`

Comment: Use `=Cells(x,y).Formula2` instead of `=Cells(x,y).Formula`

Comment: The implies that formula2 is compatible with formula local??

Comment: I am not sure abt it, but you can see here: [MSFT-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2local) and [here as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2)

Comment: Formula2 throws error 1004

Comment: Formula2 accepts only the english version which is cumbersome if the formulas in the cells are german only

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Sir, I am not very sure abt `VBA` you may raise a question on the issue you are facing with `VBA` when using the formula in the module.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Sir, ok I found one link here in `Stackoverflow` you could read this may be it helps you: [Different languages issue when inserting formula from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724156/different-languages-issue-when-inserting-formula-from-vba)

Comment: Also as per this post, in comments which is related with `German` language versions, could check as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48425122/8162520)

Comment: I translated the formula to english, it works now, but shows that the code is not creating the required results: The entries are 100, 200, 101, 102. This results in ROWS({"100";"200";"";"101";"102"}) which is reduced to a code: SEQUENZ(5,,100,100), results in {100;200;300;400;500]. The end result of this is #Überlauf - #Spill

Comment: Then there should be change in your `VBA` code, while the formula gives the required output when used in worksheet. `#Spill` because may be in other cells there are some other data, you need to clear it. also the formula (`=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Cost[Wert/BWähr];Cost[Position];SEQUENCE(ZEILEN(UNIQUE(Cost[Position]));;100;100))) `)shouldn't be spilling.

Comment: In the excel formula i can add a manuel {100,200} and it shows #spill!. So I deal with an Excel problem not an VBA problem

Comment: Yes when you write manually `={100,200}` it spills to right column wise, and the formula `=SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(C5:C24)),,100,100))` spills down bt when used within `SUM()`+`SUMIFS()` it returns a total sum of the positions cost: `=LET(α, Cost[Position], SUM(SUMIFS(Cost[Wert/BWähr],α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(α)),,100,100))))` like as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put an extra sum around th sumifs.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech sir, this is the excel sample i have used: [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck2fReY6ZxySBQ7ta?e=fwrSrp)